# Calling callbacks implemented in helper from another class

Tags: cakephp, events, cakephp-3.0

This is what my helper looks like:

```
public function implementedEvents()
{
        $mapping = parent::implementedEvents();

        $mapping += [
            'Helper.Layout.beforeFilter' => 'filter',
        ];

        return $mapping;
}

public function filter(&$content, $options = array()) {
     ...       
}
```

And I would like to call these callbacks from another class:

```
$event = new Event('Helper.Layout.beforeFilter', $View, [
      'content' => &$body,
      'options' => array()
]);
EventManager::instance()->dispatch($event);
```

So do I need to register these listeners implemented in the helper somewhere globally and how should I do this?

Comment: Register in the bootstrap.php , http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#global-event-manager

Comment: @Salines:but how can I send my helper class as a listener to 'on' function  from bootstrap.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did in the end in my helper class:

```
public function __construct(View $view, array $config = [])
{
        parent::__construct($view, $config);
        $this->_converter = new StringConverter();
        $this->_setupEvents();
}
```

And then I register my listeners with global event manager:

```
protected function _setupEvents() {
        $events = [
            'filter' => [$this, 'filter']
        ];

        foreach ($events as $callable) {
                EventManager::instance()->on("Helper.Layout.beforeFilter", $callable);
}

public function filter($event) {
 ...
}
```